# How to recalculate prices in ListBox1 after deleting

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a possapp for my bar. Everything works fine but i have to recalculate the listbox when delete 1 or more items.
This is my code for the delete button

```
Private Sub CommandButton84_Click()

Dim ItemTarget&, s, i%

s = 0

ItemTarget = ListBox1.ListCount

If ItemTarget > 0 Then

    Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem ItemTarget - 1
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        s = s + Val(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1))
    Next
    Me.TextBox1 = s
Else
    MsgBox "De lijst is reeds leeg", vbInformation, "Café De Zoete Inval"
End If

Me.TextBox4 = Me.ListBox1.ListCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Picture link https://imge.to/i/vPNo9O

Comment: Im not sure youve given us enough to work off of here. What do you mean exactly by recalc? Whats the point of the listbox? Also, delcaring variables with characters is cool and all but considered bad practice.

Comment: You are don't tell us anything about what your problem or what is not working.

Comment: The problem now is that when i click on the delete button the last item is deleted in the listbox but my textbox 4 jump to 0€. I have to recalculate that is in the listbox

Comment: As far as I can tell you're leaving out the interesting parts of your code. Please post your entire code (not a screenshot of it) so we can actually reproduce this. It seems your formatting the value for TextBox4 somewhere to a double string representation(via change event?). My best guess would be something goes awry there.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub CommandButton100_Click()

```
Dim LItem As Long

Dim IRange As Integer

Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim rows As Integer

rows = 0
```

Set sht = ActiveSheet

```
For LItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
```

ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2

```
    With Worksheets("Sheet6")

        .Cells(LItem + 7, 1) = ListBox1.List(LItem, 0)

        .Cells(LItem + 7, 2) = ListBox1.List(LItem, 1)

        .Cells(LItem + 8, 1).EntireRow.Insert

        rows = rows + 1

        End With

    With Sheets("Histo")

    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows,
```

searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

```
    If Time < "07:00:00" Then

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = Format(Date - 1, "dd-mm-yyyy")

    Else

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = Date

    End If

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ListBox1.List(LItem, 0)

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 3) = ListBox1.List(LItem, 1)

    End With
```

Next LItem

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")

ListBox1.Clear

TextBox2.Value = ""

TextBox1.Value = 0

Range("Sheet6!B5").ClearContents

For i = 1 To rows

.Cells(7, 1).EntireRow.Delete

Next

End With

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Me.ListBox1.AddItem .Range("B2").Value

Me.ListBox1.Column(1, ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = Format(Val(.Range("C2").Value),

"€#,##0.00")

Me.TextBox1.Value = CDbl(Me.TextBox1.Value) + .Range("C2").Value

Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(Me.TextBox1.Value, "#,##0.00")

End With

Me.TextBox4 = Me.ListBox1.ListCount

End Sub